# ¿Cómo llamar a un método desde un template?

Tags: django

necesito saber como puedo hacer que un botón o etiqueta  me ejecute una función que está en la views sin tener que asignarle una url, solo que al pulsarlo me ejecute el método. Saludos y gracias

Este es el método en views:

```
def generarMatriz(request, id_proyecto):
hilo = myThread(id_proyecto)
hilo.start()

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,id_proyecto):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_proyecto = id_proyecto
    def run(self):
        a = algoritmo(self.id_proyecto)
        a.principal()
```

Comment: sea de la forma que lo hagas debes tener una URL para que lea o ejecute,  otra posible solucion seria crear un tag personalizado de Django donde recibe como parametro(id_proyecto) y harias lo que desees con este

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters

Answer (score 0):

Si el procesamiento es corto lo óptimo es usar AJAX.
Si el procesamiento es pesado se suele usar Celery.

Ejecutar código Python directamente en la plantilla es una mala práctica, mucho más un hilo como haces, no es asíncrono, saturarías el servidor, sobre todo si no tienes un gestor de colas.